# Why do people say "I am home" instead of "I am at home"?

Tags: prepositions

Why do people say "I am home" in the meaning of "I am **at** home"?

Here is the person who say "I am home" he is human being and not object as home.
In addition, why people don't say "I am university" or "I am supermarket" etc?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21286/im-home-or-im-at-home

Comment: As @JavaLatte points out, this question was answered [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/21289/164910). In the phrase "I'm home", the word "home" is an adverb (compare the phrase "to go home"). PS, "I am university" or "I am supermarket" are grammatically incorrect, because these are singular nouns. Adding the article "a" would make them grammatically correct but still nonsensical.

Comment: I am at home. I am home. Both are correct. In the former sentence, home has been used as a noun. In the latter, home is an adverb that means 'at home'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Home* in this sentence is used as an **adverb**, or [adverb of place](http://www.englishcurrent.com/grammar/go-home-adverb-no-preposition/) to be more specific.

[Home](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/home#british-1-2-1) means *at or to ​your ​house or the ​place where you ​live* if used as an adverb. This is only true for *home*, not *house*.

Other places are not treated as adverbs, and hence are not used in this fashion. That's why you can't say, for example, *I am bedroom*. But when *home* is  used as a **noun**, you can say: "I'm studying **at** home"

**When is home a noun or an adverb?**

> Think about these verbs: *go*, *run*, *cook*, *buy*.
>
> - Can you *go* in a direction? **Yes**. Ok, so you can home use an adverb of place here. = I go home.
> - Can you *run* in a direction? **Yes**. Ok, so you can home use an adverb of place here. = I run  home.
> - Can you *cook* or *buy* in a direction? **Not really**. These verbs aren’t about movement or traveling. You can’t cook down/up/around, so you can’t cook home (adverb).
>     But you can **cook AT home** (noun).
>
> When home is used as a location (and not a direction), use a preposition if the verb needs one.
>   “I cook at home.” “I looked at a home.” “I bought a home.”

Source: English Current (first link)