# 'I brought them at my home' or 'I brought them to my home'?

Tags: prepositions

I want to know which preoposition should I use before the word 'home'.

Comment: "I brought them to my home" works. The other one is completely incorrect.

Comment: Well, it might not be incorrect; it depends on the circumstances. But it's almost certainly incorrect. @Jairin, you chose the right tag ("prepositions") but without knowing what the sentence is supposed to mean, it's impossible to say definitively which preposition is correct. Could you edit your question to add the circumstances which led to your "I brought..." sentence? We might then be able to determine exactly which preposition is required.

Comment: @Andrew: I think we can safely assume OP has no idea how ***at*** would change the meaning. In a pretty weird way, actually - my first attempt to contrive a valid context ended with me deciding it would be easier to assume the speaker meant ***bought***, not ***brought***. In light of that I think the question belongs on ELL, not here.

Comment: Why do you feel like you have to use any preposition? “I brought them home” is a perfectly good sentence.

Comment: I see no case where **at" would work in English here. Brought them to my home or brought them home.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do people say "I am home" instead of "I am at home"?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84703/why-do-people-say-i-am-home-instead-of-i-am-at-home)

Answer (score 1):

You've probably read or heard expressions like "I'm at John's house right now" or "Everyone is at my house today."

However, even though it may seem logical, you can't say *brought X at home*.  The preposition *at* doesn't work with *bring* in the sense of identifying a destination location.

It sounds like you are trying to say where the event or action of bringing occurred, as opposed to the destination place of the bringing.  And that may only somewhat work in some limited circumstances where context fills in the *to* or *for* part of *bring*, but not very well:

> Sally needs to bring candy for everyone this time.  I brought two candy bars at the game last time, so why do I have to do it again?  (I brought two candy bars *for everyone* at the game last time).

So, before *home* you want to use *to* or *in*.

Answer (score 1):

One

> brings *something* **to** *somewhere*
>
> I bring my lunch *to* work.
>   We brought the tour group *to* the attraction.

and one

> does *something* **at** *someplace*
>
> I write programs *at* work.
>   She got her hair cut *at* the salon.

Your example should be

> I brought them *to* my home.

or more simply

> I brought them home.

Comment: What if I want to say that I brought them to the area around my home or in a point near my home. Can I say I brought them at my home or what?

Comment: You could use "I brought them *around / near / beside / next to / close to / by*  my home" for a location close to your home.